# textItem isn't showing inside rectangle

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to draw a rectangle with a text inside. here is my piece of code

```
QGraphicsRectItem *rectangle=new QGraphicsRectItem(75,50,30,40);
QGraphicsTextItem *text=new QGraphicsTextItem("12.5",rectangle);
scene->addItem(rectangle);
```

the text isn't showing inside the rectangle.
I am under quite a bit of time pressure, it will be more helpful if you could answer in detail. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use `setPos` on the text item?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
   QGraphicsTextItem* i = pScene->addText(s);
   i->translate(dx, dy); // setPos(x, y) in newer Qt versions
```

and it works well.